# Converting Word doc to utf-8 txt on command line

Tags: command-line, utf-8, converters, docx

I'm trying to do exactly what the title of this post says.  I have a bunch of Word docs, and I would like to have UTF-8 text versions.  And I would love to do this on the command line.

I just discovered [docx2txt](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/) and it looks promising, but I can't determine whether it is capable of outputting UTF-8 text.  By default it converts `©` to `(C)`, for example.

Does anyone either:

1. Know how to get UTF-8 out of this tool?
2. ..or know of another option?

Comment: This question seems more suited to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) than Stack Overflow; it doesn't seem to be programming-related.

Comment: That's fair.  How do I move it?

Comment: It's probably simplest to simply delete it and re-create it as a "new" question over there.

Comment: or you can click the `flag` link at the bottom of your question and ask for a moderator to move it. Good luck.